# What's the http status code if a site key exceeds 1000 QPS for recaptcha?

Tags: recaptcha

in recaptcha document, it says that if a site key exceeds 1000 QPS, then some requests may not be processed, I am wondering how I can identify this error if this happens? I assume a http code of 429 is thrown by google server?

Answer (score 1):

The [reCAPTCHA-specific quota page](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/quotas) links to a more general [Google API quota page](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#quota_errors) that says

> - If you exceeded a quota with an HTTP/REST request, Google Cloud returns an `HTTP 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS` status code.
> - If you exceed a quota with an API request, Google Cloud returns an HTTP `413 REQUEST ENTITY TOO LARGE` status code.
> - If you exceeded a quota using gRPC, Google Cloud returns a ResourceExhausted error. How this error appears to you depends on the service.
> - If you exceeded a quota using a Google Cloud CLI command, the gcloud CLI outputs a quota-exceeded error message and returns with the exit code 1.

Since you mention HTTP, I imagine you're in one of the first two categories. If you're going through their REST interface, you'll get 429. If you're going through the API, you'll get 413.